# Stabiliser of a curve under Affine Transformations?

Tags: group-theory, plane-curves, affine-geometry, plane-geometry

Let $\gamma$ be a curve in the plane, and let $\text{Im}(\gamma) \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be its image in the plane. Is it possible to completely specify the affine transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which send $\text{Im}(\gamma)$ to itself?

For example, if $\gamma(t)=(t,t^{2})$, then the linear maps $(x,y) \to (\lambda x,\lambda^{2} y)$ are (I think) the whole collection of such maps. If $\gamma$ is a circle, then the orthogonal group does the trick. I would expect that "usually" the group of stabilising actions would be trivial, but I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: For clarity: I'm particularly interested in finding a reasonably large class of simple (as in easy to describe) curves for which the stabiliser is trivial (for example, I imagine that most cubic equations, but obviously not all, have this property).

Answer (score -1):

These linear maps $(x,y)→(λx,λ^2y)$ is called parabolic rescaling and is crucial in proving decoupling theorem and Vindogronov main theorem.

Now assume we have a curve defined by $f(x,y)=0$. the CORRECT ANSWER OF THIS PROBLEM is those curve that do not have "error term". I will explain what I said in the following.

1.If $f(x,y)=0$ is a plane $V$. then we know the affine map send $image(\gamma)$ to itself is just a affine map make $V$ to be a invariance subspace.

2.if $f(x,y)=0$ is a quadratic curve. Then it is easy to see $f(x,y)=0$ could not to be a elliptic. now change a basis we can assume the new basis is the eigenvalue of affine map $A$. So $Ax=\lambda_1x, Ay=\lambda_2 y$.Now I claim $f(x,y)$ should be have only two terms, every unknown quantity a term. for example $x^2-y^2,x^2-y,x^2-y$. These is just derive by $\frac{f(\lambda_1^kx,\lambda_2^ky)}{\lambda_1^{w_1k}\lambda_2^{w_2k}}= f(x,y),\forall k\in N^*$.

3.For the cubic and higher polynomial the result is similar.

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't understand your solution.  
1) I imagine you mean "if the level curve lies in a plane $V$", but then I don't understand in what sense $\text{image}(\gamma)$ is a subspace of $V$ - it need not be a vector space at all.  
2) By "quadratic curve" do you mean that $f$ is quadratic in both $x$ and $y$, or only one of them? Eigenvalues are (as far as I know) only associated to linear maps - what do you mean by the eigenvalue of an affine map?

Comment: This answer makes very little sense.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, Definitely no, you just do not understand what I am saying.

Comment: @Daniel Littlewood. You can always consider it to be a linear map by a translation, for 1, as I said, I am talking about the restriction of linear map $A$ on the plane $V$ to make $V$ invariance and this is enough. The key point of my argument is my final argument and it is very easy to understand. you just have a lots of rescaling induced by linear map $A$, and they are dense when we take it to turn infinite. This information is enough to show the structure of the polynomial is just looks like $s_1x^{k_1}+s_2y^{k_2}=0$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood, maybe you still do not believe what I am saying, maybe most focus on why I just consider the linear map but not affine map, I need to point out, the case of linear map the transform could be $T^n((x,y))=(\lambda_1^nx,\lambda_2^ny)$ while for affine map the transform could be $T^n((x,y))=(\lambda_1^nx+\gamma_1^n,\lambda_2^ny+\gamma_2^n)$, where $-1<\gamma_1,\gamma_2<1$. So this is just $O(c^{-n})$ which could be ignore.

Comment: @Huxiyu: It is a pleasant exercise to show that every quadric has nontrivial (in fact, infinite) stabilizer in the group of affine transformations.

Comment: @MoisheCohen. Yeah  I do not proof it is not the case. the result is consider after a basis transform.